# Signalr: .Net I can't connect even though I send jwt token

Tags: c#, .net, signalr, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I am generating tokens in my project with .net core 3.1. I am sending tokens in connection to the .net 6 api project where signalr is installed. token is gone. no problem. but it does not accept token. The error I get is as below.

> Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: WebSocket failed to
> connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the
> endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not
> present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you
> have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
>
> Uncaught (in promise) Error: WebSocket failed to connect. The
> connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may
> not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the
> server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple
> servers check that sticky sessions are enabled.
> at webSocket.onclose (signalr.js:2339:28)
>
> WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://localhost:60001/menushowhidehub?access_token=Bearer%20eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYmYiOjE2ODU3MDg1MjksImV4cCI6MTY4NTc5NDkyOSwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NTAwMS8iLCJhdWQiOiJodHRwczovL2xvY2FsaG9zdDo2MDAwMS8iLCJpc0F1dGhlbnRpY2F0ZWQiOnRydWUsIm5hbWUiOiJaZXluZXAgTWluZSIsInJvbGVzIjpbXSwibWFpbCI6ImluYW5zQG1vbml0b3Jjcm8uY29tIiwidXNlcklkIjoiYjk2YWYzYzYtMjRlYy00MTI3LTk4ZWYtMTA0YjY1NmViOTQ4In0.um1fiy1905_hcFQ60F0mpqkjymTtNqxAgA0bnrqUzSk'
> failed:
>
> Information: (WebSockets transport) There was an error with the
> transport.

My codes are below:

js:

```
Hub.jwtToken();
    let accessToken = Hub.getCookie("AccessToken");
    if (accessToken === "")
        return false;

    const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("https://" + url + hubName, {
            accessTokenFactory: () => 'Bearer ' + accessToken, skipNegotiation: true,
            transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets })
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();
    return connection.start();
```

appsettingjson:

```
 "Token": {
    "Issuer": "https://localhost:5001/",
    "Audience": "https://localhost:60001/",
    "SecurityKey": "adjklashfjkahfshgfhsfhskfhl123131DASDAfgvsdmnfgmösdbgmösbdmgöbsdnmgdda131g"
  },
```

api 6.0 project program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = true,
        //ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        //ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Token:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = Configuration["Token:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Token:SecurityKey"])),
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:5001/";
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnMessageReceived = context =>
        {
            var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) == false)
            {
                context.Token = accessToken;
                //context.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", new string[] { accessToken });
            }
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
});
```

Hub:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class MenuShowHideHub : Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub<IMenuShowHideInterface>
    {
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Remove "Bearer " from your token, it should just be `accessTokenFactory: () => accessToken`

Comment: @Brennan I deleted it but it still didn't work. It looks like it's giving a websocket error. It says something like websocket is not open but I don't understand.

Comment: If you delete the `Bearer` in JS, It seems to be nothing wrong in your js code. Have you checked the url you specify is correct?

Comment: @XinranShen If I don't send jwt then the request drops to the hub. but without jwt I am sending request without writing websocket code. When I want to send jwt code, I need to write websocket code. but then I also get websocket error. If I do not write the following two codes, the request goes to the hub, but this time the jwt does not  
skipNegotiation: true,
ransport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets

Comment: Strange. Refer to this [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/authn-and-authz?view=aspnetcore-7.0), I think your configuration is ok.

Comment: Hi Batu, please [enable front end logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-7.0#javascript-client-logging), and share more details for us.